# Command \leftbar already defined after using \usepackage{framed}

Tags: macros, errors, framed, compilation-error

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}



\LetLtxMacro\amsproof\proof
\LetLtxMacro\amsendproof\endproof
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem} 



\usepackage{thmtools}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \LetLtxMacro\proof\amsproof
  \LetLtxMacro\endproof\amsendproof
}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Twierdzenie}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}{Stwierdzenie}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemat}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Uwaga}[section]
\newtheorem*{uwaga}{Uwaga}
\newtheorem*{przy}{Przykład}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definicja}[section]
\newtheorem{wniosek}{Wniosek}[section]
\newtheorem*{pyt}{Pytanie}
\newtheorem*{prob}{Problem}
\newtheorem*{dowod}{Dowód}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdtheoremenv{twierdzenie}{Twierdzenie}[section]
\newmdtheoremenv{lemat}{Lemat}[section]

\declaretheorem[
  style=plain,
  thmbox={style=M,bodystyle=\normalfont},
  name=Definicja,
  within=section,
]{definicja}


\declaretheorem[
  style=plain,
  thmbox={style=M,bodystyle=\normalfont},
  name=Wniosek,
  within=section,
]{wnio}






\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert} 
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}


\begin{figure}
    \begin{framed}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{test.png}
        \caption{Test}
    \end{framed}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

This error appears if I include \usepackage{framed}:

[image]

Why? And how can I solve this error? What I want to do is to have framed pictures, and I need to use this package in order to get it work, but for some reason, it doesn't work here.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes two packages define commands with the same names. If these commands are different, those packages are usually incompatible. Sometimes it is possible to workaround this problem, sometimes not. In your case the problem is, using both `framed` and `mdframed`. A simple suggestion would be to just remove `\usepackage{framed}` from your preamble and only use `mdframed`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro\amsproof\proof
\LetLtxMacro\amsendproof\endproof
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem} 

\usepackage{thmtools}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \LetLtxMacro\proof\amsproof
  \LetLtxMacro\endproof\amsendproof
}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Twierdzenie}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}{Stwierdzenie}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemat}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Uwaga}[section]
\newtheorem*{uwaga}{Uwaga}
\newtheorem*{przy}{Przykład}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definicja}[section]
\newtheorem{wniosek}{Wniosek}[section]
\newtheorem*{pyt}{Pytanie}
\newtheorem*{prob}{Problem}
\newtheorem*{dowod}{Dowód}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdtheoremenv{twierdzenie}{Twierdzenie}[section]
\newmdtheoremenv{lemat}{Lemat}[section]

\declaretheorem[
  style=plain,
  thmbox={style=M,bodystyle=\normalfont},
  name=Definicja,
  within=section,
]{definicja}

\declaretheorem[
  style=plain,
  thmbox={style=M,bodystyle=\normalfont},
  name=Wniosek,
  within=section,
]{wnio}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{mdframed}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.png}
        \caption{Test}
    \end{mdframed}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: the framed image]

There are several more package for frames, e.g., `tcolorbox`.

BTW: I always recommend to load only those packages, that are used. Also removing all not used preamble code, is a good idea. More optimization could be done, removing explicit loading of packages, that are implicitly loaded by others, e.g., `mathtools` already loads `amsmath`.